# CMake header file that includes header files from other directory

Tags: c++, cmake, include, subdirectory

Given this tree:

```
project
 + lib
    + include
        + include_both.h
    + source
        + file1.cpp
        + file1.h
        + file2.cpp
        + file2.h
 + main_dir
    + main.cpp
```

After linking `lib` to `main_dir` with CMake, I would like header files file1.h and file2.h to not to be visible from main.cpp. I want the library to be include-able only by the include_both.h header file. How can this be done and should I even do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try making the `include` directory a `PUBLIC` one, so it is visible to consumers of the library, but keep the `source` directory private:

```
add_library(MyLib SHARED 
    source/file1.cpp
    source/file2.cpp
)

target_include_directories(MyLib 
    PUBLIC  include
    PRIVATE source
)
```

Comment: Seems to work, thanks!. But I have one more question to ask. In include_both.h I have to specify path eg. #include "../source/file1.h". Could I change that with CMake so that #include "file1.h" would be enough or it is just better to leave it as is?

Comment: @vixu Didn't realize you were just including the private headers in the public header, which is basically just a redirection. In this case, the user of `main.cpp` could simply get to the private headers by similarly including `"../source/file1.h"` as you've explained. Is this the **right** design? It is up to you, and is probably based on several attributes of your project, as discussed [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/185775/332559).